# how to extract label in processing image with tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

I am using `map` function to apply preprocessing on dataset in order to read and extract labels from file paths using `tf.data` but it returns the same label for all images
the file path is on the following shape where A is the label
**/content/drive/MyDrive/prom02/dataset/train/A0_jpg.rf.292a080422ba984985192f413101af41.jpg**

```
images_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/drive/MyDrive/prom02/dataset/train/*', shuffle=True)

images_ds = images_ds.shuffle(200)

train_size = int(image_count*0.8)
train_ds = images_ds.take(train_size)
test_ds = images_ds.skip(train_size)
len(train_ds),len(test_ds)

def hot_encode(label):
    import string
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    i=0
    while i<26:
      if label==alphabet[i]:
        label=i
        break
      i+=1
    label=tf.one_hot(label,26)
    return label
def get_label(file_path):
    import os
    label=(str(file_path).split('/')[-1][0])
    label= hot_encode(label)
    return label
def scale(image,label):
    return image/255, label
def process_image(file_path):
    label = tf.cast(get_label(file_path),tf.float32)
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path) # load the raw data from the file as a string
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [320, 320])
    return tf.cast(img,tf.float32), label

train_ds = train_ds.map(process_image).map(scale).batch(32).cache().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.map(process_image).map(scale).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
for img,label in train_ds.take(1):
  print(label.numpy())
```

the result is always the encoded tensor of letter T as label
while when i use

```
for img in images_ds.take(2):
  print(get_label(img.numpy()))
```

it returns the true label

Comment: `train_ds.take(1)` in your for loop returns batch of items (32 in your case). If you want to access label of the first item, you should take a look at `label[0]`. `images_ds` is not batched so it returns images one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to introduce some modifications, in order to make your code clean do not extract labels inside map function, create list of both path and labels, try this one:

```
from glob import glob
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
idx = range(26)
#create dict alphabet -> idx
dict_alpha = dict(tuple(zip(alphabet, idx)))

paths = glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/prom02/dataset/train/*.jpg')
labels = []
for path in paths:
  alpha = path.split("/")[-1][0]
  labels.append(dict_alpha[alpha])

#split paths, labels using train_test_split sklearn
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((paths, labels))
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(len(paths))

def process_image(file_path, label):
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, [320, 320], method = 'nearest')
  return img, tf.one_hot(label, 26)
        
    
batch = 1 #for test   

train_ds = train_ds.map(process_image).batch(batch).cache().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    
for img, label in train_ds.take(1):
  print(label)
```

Observations:

- You can just replace the scale mapping by img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32) inside
  process_image
- `tf.image.resize(img, [320, 320])` by default the resizing `method is 'bilinear'` which is going change pixel values, for images i prefer `tf.image.resize(img, [320, 320], method='nearest')` which has no effect on the pixel values, it is based on duplications.